# Why sql case is not working on null condition of int column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have used SQL CASE statement on an INT type of column of a table.
Following is the SQL table schema and query which is working fine.

**SQL Query**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_A(ID BIGINT ,ACCEPTED INT)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_A VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_A(ID) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_A(ID) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_A(ID) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_A VALUES(5,1)

SELECT T.ID,T.ACCEPTED,
(CASE WHEN(T.ACCEPTED=1) THEN 'ACCEPTED' ELSE 'NOT ACCEPTED' END) AS STATUS
FROM #TEMP_A T
```

**Query OUTPUT**

```
ID  ACCEPTED    STATUS
1   1           ACCEPTED
2   NULL        NOT ACCEPTED
3   NULL        NOT ACCEPTED
4   NULL        NOT ACCEPTED
5   1           ACCEPTED
```

But now problem is here that I have a condition that I need to print not accepted in select statement so I tried following query

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT T.ID,T.ACCEPTED,
(CASE WHEN(T.ACCEPTED=NULL) THEN 'NOT ACCEPTED' END) AS STATUS
FROM #TEMP_A T
```

**Query Actual OUTPUT**

```
ID  ACCEPTED    STATUS
1   1           NULL
2   NULL        NULL
3   NULL        NULL
4   NULL        NULL
5   1           NULL
```

**Query Required OUTPUT**

```
ID  ACCEPTED    STATUS
1   1           NULL
2   NULL        NOT ACCEPTED
3   NULL        NOT ACCEPTED
4   NULL        NOT ACCEPTED
5   1           NULL
```

I have to print status of those which are not accepted in select statement
what should I do to get required result.

Comment: Use `WHEN T.ACCEPTED IS NULL` instead of `WHEN(T.ACCEPTED=NULL)`.

Comment: NULL in SQL means unknown. i.e. `T.Accepted=NULL` means `is T.Accepted equal to an unknown value`. The answer is never true so the THEN clause is not executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT T.ID,T.ACCEPTED,
(CASE WHEN T.ACCEPTED IS NULL THEN 'NOT ACCEPTED' END) AS STATUS
FROM #TEMP_A T
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `IS NULL` to check for a `NULL` value.  Try this query:

```
SELECT T.ID,T.ACCEPTED,
(CASE WHEN (T.ACCEPTED IS NULL) THEN 'NOT ACCEPTED' END) AS STATUS
FROM #TEMP_A T
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `IS NULL` to check if it's `NULL`

```
SELECT T.ID,T.ACCEPTED,
(CASE WHEN(T.ACCEPTED IS NULL) THEN 'NOT ACCEPTED' END) AS STATUS
FROM #TEMP_A T
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of difference..

```
SELECT 
   T.ID
   , T.ACCEPTED,
   , ISNULL(
       CASE 
          WHEN T.ACCEPTED = 1 
             THEN 'ACCEPTED' ELSE NULL
          END
     , 'NOT ACCEPTED') AS STATUS
FROM #TEMP_A T
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do something like this :) , since you are using SQL Server, why not use `ISNULL` built-in function of SQL.

```
    SELECT T.ID,T.ACCEPTED,
    (CASE WHEN(ISNULL(T.ACCEPTED,'') = '') THEN 'NOT ACCEPTED' END) AS STATUS
    FROM #TEMP_A T
```

Comment: this syntax will also return *NOT ACCEPTED* when *T.ACCEPTED* = 0